# Swift 3 - How to open the calendar for editing when adding an event

Tags: ios, swift, save, edit, ekeventstore

I'm using the EKEventStore save(_:span:commit:) method with an "Add To Calendar" button in my app. My problem is that this method immediately saves the event. This obliges the user to then open their calendar to, for instance, add a reminder. Can anyone suggest a way to seamlessly open the calendar prior to saving the event, thus giving the user a chance to edit it (or cancel out) first?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about iOS (you really should tag your question either osx or ios), you can use [EventKitUI](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkitui#). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42755405/1271826.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Very simple and works like a charm. Also provided me with some much needed insight into how EKEventStore and EKEventEditViewController work and interact. And thanks for the advice on tagging questions.